# Copy an entire row based of finding a value on column A from another Excel file

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I have two Excel files:

1. about 175k rows and 6.5k columns - column A has some unique numbers and the rest of them some repetitive values
2. about 600k rows and 2 columns - column A has some unique numbers and column B has some repetitive text

Based on column A from Excel 2 where I have some unique numbers, I need to match them with column A from Excel 1. Once done, the rest of the row needs to be copied somehow (the repetitive values) into another sheet. Once done, based on the data copied, we need to identify the value from column A Excel 1 that has on the rest of the rows one or more of the repetitive values.

Comment: do you have any sample vba of what have you tried thus far?

Comment: Why is this tagged mysql?

Answer (score 1):

So you question isn't very specific, which is making it kind of hard to answer. However, I believe I understand what you are asking.

I am assuming that you will have one of these workbooks open. (Either 'Excel 1' or 'Excel 2' and then want to run a macro to do your heavy lifting. Here is some sample code for you to try out. I am assuming that you will start with 'Excel 1' open and then I will have your matches be copied to a new worksheet instead of a new workbook.

```
Dim wbk as Workbook
Dim Total1Rows as Long
Dim Total2Rows as Long
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim NewRows as Int
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(" file location of 'Excel 2' ")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = "Pick a Name"
Total1Rows = Worksheets(" 'Excel 1' name of worksheet ").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Total2Rows = wbk.Worksheets(" 'Excel 2' name of worksheet ").UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 1 to Total1Rows
    For j = 1 to Total2Rows
        If Worksheets(" 'Excel 1' name of worksheet ").Range("A" & i) = wbk.Worksheets(" 'Excel 2' Name of Worksheet ").Range("A" & j) Then
            NewRows = Worksheets(ws.Name).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            wbk.Worksheets(" 'Excel 2' name of worksheet").Range("A" & j & ":Z" & J).Copy
            Worksheets(" 'Excel 1' name of worksheet").Range("A" & NewRows).PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

This is actually my first time ever posting an answer so please be forgiving.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately i cannot run this and i can`t seem to understand why.

Comment: You cannot run this because you have to replace several of the things in the code with the specific names of things in your workbooks. Such as the names of the workbooks and the names of the specific worksheets. If you read through the code you will see where I wrote what you specifically need to add.